# Show Instagram login page

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I am using login with `Instagram` in my application. Now when I logged out from my application and again want to logged in to app via `Instagram`. I want to show  `Instagram login Page`, but it is giving authorised url and directly giving the user data which i used previously for logged in.

Comment: You need to 'logout' from Instagram too, and to do that, you need to delete the user token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to  clear the cache also, write the following code inside logged out button, for more information see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838785/how-to-log-out-of-the-instagram-api)

```
  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
         for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];

    }
```