# Instagram API logout link not working anymore

Tags: instagram-api

Does anybody know why this link is not working?

https://instagram.com/accounts/logout

One week ago it was working, but now it doesn't log me out anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

Probably problems with the Instagram API, is it completely necessary to use the logout URL?, because it seems that you could only delete the token. If the user doesn't want your app to access their data they will cancel your app access. See: [How to log out of the instagram API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838785/how-to-log-out-of-the-instagram-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Even if I delete the token, the browser still has me logged in. This means when I go to the authorization url, I don't see the username and password input fields. I'm writing an application for a photo print station, where different users need to log in order to see their personal photos. So I must have a way of completely log out the user after the printing process is completed.