# Sign out from Instagram via API call

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instagram

I am trying to create an Application to upload a picture using intents into Instagram.My problem is once uploaded i want to sign out from that account so some other user can sign in later. Is there a way?

Found this link

[Instagram Api User Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991753/instagram-api-user-logout)

Unable to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Instagram API doesn't give endpoint, which allows to log user out. Answer, which you reference to, recommends to use intercept url with html page - it'll load logout url in iframe and redirect to auth website. So you won't really log out user - he'll be logged out just before auth process.

Html for loading page can be as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function load() {
        window.location.href = "https://YOURS_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_URL";
      }
    </script>

    <iframe src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/"" 
    onload="load()"
    width="0" height="0">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This Instagram URL no longer works, they changed the logout process.